# Не отправляет запрос Ajax в Django

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, ajax, django

Не отправляется запрос ajax в функцию django - в консоли выводит ошибку: 500.

Это **во вьюхе:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def resource_create_multiblank(request):
    print('ok')
    return HttpResponse('update')
```

**url:**

```
path('<slug:slug>/create/multiblank/', views.resource_create_multiblank, name='resource-create-multiblank'),
```

**JS:**

```
function generateBlank(slug) {
    if (localStorage['persons'] != "[]" && localStorage['persons'] != undefined) {
        
        console.log(localStorage['persons']);
        console.log(slug);

        $.ajax({
            url: "create/multiblank/",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'persons': localStorage['persons'],
                'service': slug,
            },
            success: function (data) {
               console.log('OK');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error Server');
            },
            dataType: "json",
        });
    };
};
```

в **Шаблоне**:

```
<a herf="#" name="{{ slug }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" onclick="generateBlank(name);"></a>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Есть предположение, что ошибка банальна: не передается параметр slug в адрес. Если так - как мне правильно ее передать?

пробовал так:

**JS:**

```
url: "{% url 'resource-create-multiblank' "+slug+" %}",
```

и так:

```
url: "/"+slug+"/create/multiblank/",
```

В этом случае выдавала 404 ошибку.

Для того, чтобы работал POST Ajax выше прописал:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
};

const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного разобравшись в коде, получил следующий результат:

**В шаблоне:**

```
<a name="{% url 'resource-create-multiblank' slug %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" onclick="generateBlank(name);"></a>
```

**В JS:**

```
function generateBlank(url) {
    if (localStorage['persons'] != "[]" && localStorage['persons'] != undefined) {

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'persons': localStorage['persons'],
        },
        success: function (data) {
           console.log('OK');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error Server');
        },
        dataType: "json",
    });
};
};
```

**view:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def resource_create_multiblank(request, slug):
    ....
    return JsonResponse(msg, safe=False)
```